# Calling a javascript adapter from javascript client gets 415 Unsupported Media Type response

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

In MFF8.0, calling a javascript adapter from javascript client gets 415 Unsupported Media Type response.
client code:

```
    var parameters = [{ 'project_code': '123', 'name': 'ABC', 'type': 'A' }];
    var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/myAdapter/search, WLResourceRequest.POST);
    resourceRequest.setTimeout(60000);
    resourceRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
    if (parameters === undefined) {
        resourceRequest.send().then(function(res){
            dfd.resolve(res);
        },function(){
            dfd.reject();
        });
    } else {
        resourceRequest.send(parameters[0]).then(function(res){
            dfd.resolve(res);
        },function(){
            dfd.reject();
        });
    }
```

javascript adapter:

```
function search(p) {
  MFP.Logger.info(“searching…”);
  if (p) {
    var pj = checkDefaultValue(p.project_code);
    var name = checkDefaultValue(p.name);
    var type = checkDefaultValue(p.type);
    return search(pj,name,type); // this returns Javascript object
  } else return {};
 }
```

In server-side, no log, such as “searching…”, is generated, and response code is 415.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have any Input/output Filters which are validating the input ? Is it possible for you to share the network trace? Does not look like the Adapter is getting called, I beleive response is given from some other layer

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Content-Type of your resourceRequest to application/ x-www-form-urlencoded.

Add this line in your code

resourceRequest.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form urlencoded');

refer  [duplicate SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47415586/mobilefirst-adapter-invocation-failed-with-unsupported-media-type-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I updated "Content-Type" header as you suggested, but the result is not changed. Still getting 415 Unsupported Media Type response.

Comment: Do you have any Input/output Filters which are validating the input ? Is it possible for you to share the network trace? Does not look like the Adapter is getting called, I beleive response is given from some other layer –